# How to add custom header for requestretry?

Tags: node.js, request

My call is like this,

```
const { get, post } = require('requestretry');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const [getAsync, postAsync] = [get, post].map(promisify);

    const res = await postAsync({
        url: "some url",
        json: messageObj, // request body
        maxAttempts: 5,
        retryDelay: 1000
    });
```

Where can i add custom header please ?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/requestretry?activeTab=readme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const res = await postAsync({
    url: "some url",
    headers: {...},
    json: messageObj, // request body
    maxAttempts: 5,
    retryDelay: 1000
});
```